# What does the coordinates node do?

Tags: node-editor

The input node, in Blender Render, called ["coordinates"](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/nodes/types/input/coordinates.html):

outputs the geometry local coordinates, relative to its bounding box as RGB colors.

But the coordinates of what object?

No matter what I do to any object in my scene, the coordinate node outputs the exact same image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this kind of configuration :

[image]

The bounding box is considered as a local space from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 1, 1), and each vertex of your mesh has a position into this bounding box. The '*coordinates*' node gives this position.

Here with a sphere, no vertex has coordinates greater than 0.8, so you don't have any white part (this is a top view) :

[image]

Comment: oh so the texture isnt meant to change? Only the mapping of the texture changes based on the coordinates of the vertices?

Comment: @eromod, yes as all objects have proportionally the same bounding box. Only the vertices positions relatively to the bounding box matters.